# Blender Can't detect 3D hardware accelerated Driver

Tags: gpu, installation

I have just installed blender 2.77a from blender.org om windows 8.1.
When i try to open blender it gives me an error as follows

> Blender - Can't detect 3d hardware accelerated drivers.

[image: Blender - Can't detect 3d hardware accelerated drivers.]

I have checked my graphics card driver via windows update and it says my drivers are up to date. My graphics driver details are as follows (dxdiag) :

```
---------------
Display Devices
---------------
          Card name: Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.1)
       Manufacturer: Intel Corporation
          Chip type: Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family
           DAC type: Internal
        Device Type: Full Device
         Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_2A42&SUBSYS_02631028&REV_07
     Display Memory: 1065 MB
   Dedicated Memory: 64 MB
      Shared Memory: 1001 MB
       Current Mode: 1280 x 800 (32 bit) (60Hz)
       Monitor Name: Generic PnP Monitor
      Monitor Model: unknown
         Monitor Id: LPL0000
        Native Mode: 1280 x 800(p) (59.976Hz)
        Output Type: Internal
        Driver Name: igdumd64.dll,igd10umd64.dll,igdumd32,igd10umd32
Driver File Version: 8.15.0010.2702 (English)
     Driver Version: 8.15.10.2702
        DDI Version: 10
     Feature Levels: 10.0,9.1
       Driver Model: WDDM 1.1
Graphics Preemption: DMA
 Compute Preemption: DMA
           Miracast: Not Supported
Hybrid Graphics GPU: Not Applicable
     Power P-states: Not Applicable
  Driver Attributes: Final Retail
   Driver Date/Size: 3/11/2013 15:49:02, 6593816 bytes
        WHQL Logo'd: Yes
D3D9 Overlay: Supported
            DXVA-HD: Supported
       DDraw Status: Enabled
         D3D Status: Enabled
         AGP Status: Enabled
```

Please tell me how i can solve this problem.

Comment: Same problem here with the driver error. Downloaded direct from website suggested above. Didn't work - still exact same error. Did OP ever get the problem solved? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You should get "software" OpenGL:

1. Go to this link: http://download.blender.org/ftp/sergey/softwaregl/
2. Pick your OS version (86/64).
3. Put the opengl32.dll file into your top Blender installation folder (C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender). This should be the same location as your blender.exe file.

Blender should start.

Comment: i did this and it just crash. nice job sir.

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: I installed the file from Blender http://download.blender.org/ftp/sergey/softwaregl/win64/opengl32.dll into `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender` on a virtual Machine. Since now it is able to run without exception "No graphic card found". Now with success.

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: This Works for me

Answer (score 4):

Blender uses OpenGL for just about anything (except rendering the final result) – Direct3D is no use to it, because Blender is cross plattform and Direct3D exists only in Windows. Hence you require a working, fully supported OpenGL implementation installed on your system. Microsoft years ago decided to actively sabotage OpenGL by stripping everything that is OpenGL from the GPU drivers that are installed through Windows Update and just leave around a software fallback for OpenGL-1.1 (totally outdated version from 1996).

The only way to get proper OpenGL support on Windows is to install the graphics drivers directly from the GPU vendor, i.e. the driver packages you can download directly from Intel, AMD, NVidia and so on. In your case you need the original Intel drivers installed.

Comment: i tried that too. But when i try to install drivers downloaded from dell the installer says : This computer does not meet the minimum requirements for installing the software.

Comment: so i don't know how to run away from Microsoft's drivers.

Comment: @RanaAliRaza: Dell does not make GPUs. Intel made your GPU. You want to download from here: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26078/Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-10-and-Windows-7-8-1-15-40-?product=80939

Comment: Is downloading the drivers with geforce experience direct enough? I downloaded and installed my nvidia drivers multiple times with geforce experience and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Both answers are valid with possible requirement of updating chipset code drivers and the loading opengl32.dll into the blender folder. Make sure its in the Programs folder or programs(86) depending on location 64 bit or 32 bit Blender folder respectively. Some of the newer computers or my engineering computer did not require the updated chipset drivers and Linux version didnt need drivers at all.