# Receiving error "Can't Detect 3D Hardware accelerated"

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

My computer just updated, prior to the update I was able to use Blender but now I am receiving this error from blender when I open it.

[image]
http://s21.postimg.org/gaigi523r/screenshot_3.png Also I notice that when I check my Display adapters in device manager they have errors,

[image]
http://s21.postimg.org/wvq2xst7r/screenshot_2.png.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Need more info from me just let me know.  I did do some searching before I posted my question but could't find anything that I could understand. Thank You for your time.

Comment: I did a dxdiag run and here are the results http://s21.postimg.org/4bbjoklwn/screenshot_4.png.

Comment: re-install the drivers for your graphics card

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blender Can't detect 3D hardware accelerated Driver](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60236/blender-cant-detect-3d-hardware-accelerated-driver)

Answer (score 1):

After Windows updating, they use "Microsoft basics display drivers". This is drivers for something like "emergency mode". They work, but they doesn't use all hardware features.

You need to install appropriate Intel graphics drivers from Intel website.
I never had Intel Graphics, but this look like page for download:

[intel download center](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/)

Comment: Thank for getting back to me, I am in my system info and this is what I see, http://s21.postimg.org/qjfj1pfjb/screenshot_5.png. Do you know what info tells me which graphic driver I need from this list? https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/80939/Graphics-Drivers   I'm looking through the list but I'm not sure which one I should get.

Comment: maybe should be better install drivers from HP website. http://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers   Here you can choose by your laptop model .no, also there is video where you can find it. Anyway, this is not question related to Blender, this is about Windows system, so I thing this will be deleted soon