# Error on Launch "Can't Detect 3d Hardware Accelerated Driver"

Tags: game-engine

I'm not sure if this is a valid question, but it's about launching Bender?

Every time I try to open blender, it just says this:
[image: something about graphics or something]

Even though whenever I checked, it DID use the hardware acceleration?

Comment: with blender 2.77+ you need a card supporting 2.1 opengl, it could be just that. try blender 2.76, it could work (needs opengl 1.4)

Comment: and why is this tagged game-engine??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blender Can't detect 3D hardware accelerated Driver](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60236/blender-cant-detect-3d-hardware-accelerated-driver)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment on m.ardito's comment due to my rep level. But, I want to add that I was having this problem with version 2.78 when I got this error. I went to SourceForge and found version 2.76. I did get the message when I started the app. But, in this version you are allowed to proceed to open and use the app. The message is just a warning with version 2.76.

I haven't had any problems so far. But, I'm only doing simple beginner stuff.

I should note that I am using library computers and running the Portable version off my flash drive. Some of the library computers will run version 2.78 and some won't. There are about 50 computers in each of the different library branches I visit. None of the computers are configured the same way. And, they just started installing Win 10 on some computers, which may cause...who knows what.

Comment: Don't go to SourceForge, all Blender releases can be found on http://download.blender.org/release/

Answer (score 0):

You should get "software" OpenGL:

1. Go to this link: http://download.blender.org/ftp/sergey/softwaregl/
2. Pick your OS version (86/64).
3. Put the opengl32.dll file into your top Blender installation folder (C:\Program         Files\Blender Foundation\Blender). This should be the same location as your blender.exe file.

Blender should start.