# Blender App opens in worst resolution and the info bar is invisible

Tags: windows

Blender opens on a worst resolution, the the info bar isn't visible and edges of the app overlaps on the screen, I have attached the picture below.

Drivers are updated. Here are my machine specs

- Windows 10 Pro 64 bit
- Core™ i5-7200U
- Integrated Intel® HD Graphics 620
- 8GB RAM

[image]

**EDIT**:
I have Intel HD 620, and i real dont have a clue what drivers version works perfect with blender as for [The "Info" bar on top disappeared and the mouse pointer is misaligned](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82130/the-info-bar-on-top-disappeared-and-the-mouse-pointer-is-misaligne), its the (Intel HD 530 version 15.45.19.4678) that was causing problems.

Comment: The message at opening Blender from console shown above is a low priority warning which isn't related to the problem you have. If you really want to fix it then see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77857/error-al-lib-updatedeviceparams-failed-to-set-44100hz-got-48000hz-instead-wh. As to the top part of Blender window see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82130/the-info-bar-on-top-disappeared-and-the-mouse-pointer-is-misaligned.

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77857/error-al-lib-updatedeviceparams-failed-to-set-44100hz-got-48000hz-instead-wh

Comment: @MrZak i kinder thought the error might be related, by the way, its not a big deal so i wont bother, so i think now the issue might be on the graphics drivers, and this is different with the one i have (Intel HD 620)  i am not quite sure if rolling back would solve the problem! any suggestions on that?

Comment: It's hard to tell specifically. This can be related if Blender was working normally and suddenly stopped once drivers were updated. Other than that this is only to try and see as the similar case was about drivers. One way to check is download OpenGL dll from https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60236/blender-cant-detect-3d-hardware-accelerated-driver and put it in the Blender's folder (not permanently). If everything starts normally then the problem is graphic drivers

Comment: @MrZak thanks buddy for the clues you gave me, seems the problem was caused by the custom manufacture drivers, of which i have managed to solve it :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some time spent troubleshooting, i figured out the customer Lenovo updated Intel HD 620 Driver is the one that conflicting with blender, i am not quite sure if its the same thing happening to  [The "Info" bar on top disappeared and the mouse pointer is misaligned](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82130/the-info-bar-on-top-disappeared-and-the-mouse-pointer-is-misaligned) (Either with Lenovo or Other Manufactures).

The easy quick solution to this is uninstalling the Manufacture maintained Driver and installing the Generic Intel Driver.

Or rolling back to same previous Manufacture maintained Drivers (Of which it might take a lot of trials and not guaranteed to solve the problem since you might not have a clue on which one was working perfectly with blender).