# CUDA, 3D Hardware & Nvidia driver, my Blender goes crazy

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, hardware

First I want to say that yesterday everything worked fine for me. 
Let's start.
When I launched the blender this morning, I saw this:

[image]

I very quickly found a solution to this problem ([Blender Can't detect 3D hardware accelerated Driver](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60236/blender-cant-detect-3d-hardware-accelerated-driver)), did everything as written, but now the program has begun to slow down very much. It is **impossible** to work.

- I reinstalled blender. Did not help.
- I downloaded a new driver for the video card - and oh, a miracle! - It worked! But not for long. After a couple of minutes, everything hung and again does not work.

So, right now I have 3 condition of Blender 2.79b:

- do nothing = "Can't detect 3D hardware...."
- download opengl32.dll = slow down, no CUDA

[image: no CUDA]

- installed a new NVIDIA driver = everything is fine, but only the first couple of minutes, then closes and error again (about 3d) or freezing if opengl32.dll in folder .

[image: fine]

Disconnected Intel(R) HD Graphics - did not help. What else can I do?

System Info: Windows 10 Home, x64, Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz, 16 GB, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, Driver 411.70

Comment: I don't know the solution to your problem. But in your situation. I would maybe start looking at the option of having a dual boot machine (no cynicism intended). My own experience is blender and similar software work much better on Linux.

Comment: Hi I reworked a bit your question text source: you don't need to insert HTML tags like <br>, just separate sentences with a blank line and it will have the same effect. Also space images in the same way.

Comment: Downloading opengl32.dll into Blender folder is avoiding any GPU usage (and it's meant for that so don't use it if you want to use your GPU). Check if Windows 10 in faith belief it helps didn't updated your Nvidia drivers to something graphic apps don't support (like e.g. here https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2261/blender-is-currently-unusable-on-nvidia-gpus-m-mx-family). Fact that everything is fine with new driver for little time is quite weird, it's like driver is rolled back by something automatically.

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem was in NVIDIA driver. I downloaded an earlier version of the driver(**391.25** instead **411.70**). I think I will not update them for a long time.

Comment: It happens. There is no need not to update. The best thing to do is to be aware that once in while a driver update has a bug. The proceedure is quite simple and do not take a lot of time even though it is unpleasant and a bit frustrating. Now that you are aware of it, solving a similar problem will not take much time in the future, but with driver updates you might get performace and stability gains as well. There is no need not to carry on updates after a few months once this is likely to be fixed.