# Blender 3d hardware error

Tags: gpu, error, hardware

I had blender 2.78 installed on my pc working greatly on windows 8.
But as soon as I updated my window to windows 10, blender shows me this error "Blender - Can't detect 3D hardware accelerated driver!". I know I can install openGL 2.1 and its not a big issue, but I want to know why this error occurred only when I updated my windows?
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blender Can't detect 3D hardware accelerated Driver](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60236/blender-cant-detect-3d-hardware-accelerated-driver)

Comment: Because windows "*helped*" you.

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be one satisfying explanation about why this happens when you update Windows. This is just something that happens sometimes when updating Windows - stuff breaks sometimes. Microsoft is a company, people work in it, people make mistakes. Something just went wrong during the update.

Also one does not install OpenGL. OpenGL comes as a part of your graphics drivers instead, so you can update the graphics drivers. Updating the graphics drivers should be the first thing to do when you get an error message like that from Blender.

Comment: Well, actually there is. An Upgrade from one Windows Version to another doesn't necessarily upgrade all the drivers. So most likely the proper drivers for the GPU got thrown out and the Computer runs with the standard drivers provided by Windows 10.

Comment: I just don't think this is a logical explanation that makes any difference. There is no apparent reason for Windows update to do this from the user's perspective and the result makes no sense. Windows update just messes things up in this case - that's what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Report such issues to Blender  developers as yours is **yet** another post here about problems with Blender on Windows 10. Perhaps they should drop Microsoft guys a word. It seems downgrading/not upgrading Windows is the only way out of this for the time being.

Comment: This seems like a driver issue. It makes sense to try the usual troubleshooting steps before troubling developers with it. Maybe the graphics driver got uninstalled or disabled during the update or something simple like that happened. Reporting issues that are not related to actual Blender's functionality will just waste time of the developers. I think this is not a good idea. Windows 10 and all versions of it can be configured in thousands of different ways - it makes sense that some problems happen. They are usually not that difficult to resolve. Don't bother developers with this.

Comment: Yes, plenty of us use Blender on windows 10 with no issues. As Martynas points out, windows pcs have infinite possibilities for hardware and software, compared to, say, Mac, where the options for customization are tightly controlled by Apple.